# Экспорт данных из WP в CSV в виде ссылки

Tags: wordpress, веб-программирование, csv, wordpress-плагины, export

Подскажите пожалуйста плагин, который может экспортировать данные с интернет-магазина на WordPress в CSV файл в виде ссылки (т.е. не выгрузка на локальный ПК или сервер в виде файла, а генерация ссылки с данными). Также необходима возможность автоматической регулярной выгрузки (например, раз в сутки или раз в час).

Comment: Что значит "ссылка с данными"? Хочешь в GET передать весть контент всех товаров? [Проблема XY](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/709/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-xy/710#710) не иначе. Для чего это понадобилось? В чём задача?

Comment: Задача состоит в том, что необходимо настроить автоматический обмен с Instagram магазином и необходимо это автоматизировать. Допустим, генерятся раз в день данные и раз в день фейсбук обращается по указанной ссылке, забирает оттуда данные и подгружает в инстаграм магазин

Comment: Для этого в ВП существует REST API. Но что может ин100грамм я не знаю.

Comment: А если они умеют скачивать файлы csv, то плагином можно генерить именно на сервер в публичный каталог с постоянной ссылкой, которую и скормить мордокнижникам. Но это не очень вариант по многим причинам.

Comment: И вообще.. https://wordpress.org/plugins/facebook-for-woocommerce/